# CPU overheating on startup

Tags: cpu, computer-building, overheating

I just built a new PC, and on startup in the bios it already shows my CPU overheating at 190 degrees. Can anyone explain what is happening? I have 4 fans, 2 in and 2 out. This is literally the first time I ran the computer.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Have you overclocked? is it stock fan or bought one? what does the fan sound like?

Comment: @Andrew Crawford it is not over clocked. All fans sound what I would consider normal.

Comment: @AndrewCrawford I am editing the post with a picture of heatsink

Comment: stock fan, and from eh look of it intel one, as mentioned below make sure it clicked in the intel one are pains to make sure they are if you ain't sure take it to a local shop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may happen if you used not enough thermal paste. The thermal paste should be fresh as much as possible. If the thermal paste it older than two years it is not recommended to apply. If it is not all-in-one CPU + Cooler in the box, then cooler should be chosen smartly to match your CPU. The cooler should be checked to be connected and moving all the time.

Comment: Thermal paste came applied to CPU.

Comment: Most guys assembling PCs would confirm it is not enough. You should apply more thermal paste in there.

Comment: @JordanD - Are you sure because you are exceeding the thernal limits of the CPU by about 10 degrees,

Comment: How much paste should I apply? I am sure though.

Comment: When it spread it should cover all the contacting square between CPU and Cooler. Be sure it is not out from the square as the paste itself is conductible. Watch this [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o7rPqCvCt0g)

Comment: Also make sure you have attached the heatsink correctly. It needs to be fully seated and locked down. Even the slightest gap means the heatsink is not in contact with the paste (and thus the CPU) - causing the problem. We once had a technician replace a CPU but he didn't push the heatsink on far enough (he thought it had locked) and it kept overheating the moment we powered the machine on. I then re-attached the heatsink and all was good again.

Comment: There could be multitude of reasons for it thermal paste can cause it but generally doesn't i have run cpus at full 100% with no thermal paste but the heatsink and fan connected perfectly, but need more details to suggest best way forward here. Oh tip for anyone if you ever want to see what temperature a cpu runs to with no fan well it hot don't touch it i can assure you it hot approx 150C+

Comment: 150C+ it can be, but not working. Well that's as for modern CPU, by the way low speed microcontroller could be still working. The maximum temperature at which OS was working I saw at 123C, the same second it went to failure and shutdown.

Comment: @RuslanGerasimov it covers the whole area between the CPU and cooler.

Comment: @BigChris it seems locked down to me, though it was VERY difficult to lock down. Does that indicate I may have done it incorrectly? Is there a certain direction that is the 'top' even though it is a square?

Comment: @RuslanGerasimov I added a picture of paste

Comment: @RuslanGerasimov oh i wasn't testing if OS could load i was doing a test for the manufacturer to see the point if failed, most i have seen a OS run is 80-90 before failing

Comment: Adding more paste ended up working, thank you very much.